# NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 in 2560x1600 resolution

Tags: hdmi, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to connect HP LP3065 30" monitor to NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 card.

This graphics card has HDMI and DVI outputs. When I connect this monitor to HDMI, it works fine but the resolution is limited to 1280x800. This seems to be limitation of HDMI. Ok.

When I connect it to DVI output (with the dual link DVI cable), the 2560x1600 resolution shows up in the  NVIDIA control panel. But when I select it, the monitor cannot synhcronize and displays only horz moving lines. Even worse. Any other screen resolution and color depth does not work either.

I do not see any check boxes of similar that I can tweak. Any ideas on what to try?

Comment: Related info: http://support.plugable.com/plugable/topics/hp_lp3065_will_only_go_to_1200_x_800_resolution

Comment: From [Wikipedia on DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Technical_overview), "there can be a problem if both the digital and analog inputs in the DVI-I port detect activity." Do you happen to have a [dual-link DVI-D](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-peripheral/3365585/how-tell-dvi-i-dvi-d-cables-apart/) cable available to test with, so that there is no analog signal to potentially confuse things?

Comment: I use digital-only cable (9 pins goup + other 9 pins goup). I have not tried the full cablle. But from what you are writing, digital only cable seems to be better...

Comment: @Kirill Oh well, it was worth checking. (P.S. If you use "@username" in a reply, like I did at the start of this comment, then the person you're replying to gets notified.)